# Comma in DoubleDouble Quotes in CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I have a string like given in the example:

```
data = '02 JAN 2014,FEB 2014,A,1.00,,,""1,235.100000"",""1,230.00"",Column'
```

how can I parse this string with using python's `csv` module?

```
data = StringIO.StringIO(data) 
reader = csv.reader(data, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

It separates the the string `""1,235.10000""` to two column: `'""1'` and `'235.1000""'`

how can I fix this and arrange the module to not to split commas if its in double-double quotes?

Comment: What do you want to be returned?  `""1,235.1000000""`?  `"1,235.1000000"`? `1,235.1000000`?

Comment: @mgilson: ah, the `csv` module also splits the column into two when quoting is left to the default. The double-double-quote is seen as an empty string and removed from the column.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I'm not so sure that csv by itself is the tool for the job here ... I think it only allows for quoting with a single character, not 2 characters.  Of course, you *could* `str.replace` (or `re.sub` if you really needed to) the 2 characters for a different single character that you could quote on ...

Comment: @mgilson i want it to return this number without seperating it.

Comment: @AlperTokgöz -- But do you want to preserve the quotes or not?

Comment: @mgilson, actually it doesnt matter as long as it seperates the values correctly, it can preserve quotes or not.

Comment: @mgilson, you are right. i copy-paste data from the csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is good enough, but:

```
>>> import csv
>>> data = '02 JAN 2014,FEB 2014,A,1.00,,,""1,235.100000"",""1,230.00"",Column'
>>> reader = csv.reader([data.replace('""', '|')], quotechar='|')
>>> next(reader)
['02 JAN 2014', 'FEB 2014', 'A', '1.00', '', '', '1,235.100000', '1,230.00', 'Column']
```

You can keep with the `StringIO` or whatever, but passing in a list made the example code simpler :).  If you actually have a file object, you could even just use a simple generator to transform the lines before you feed them to your reader:

```
def transform(file):
   for line in file:
       yield line.replace('""', '|')

with open('foo') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(transform(fin), quotechar='|')
    ...
```

And `transform` can become as sophisticated as you like -- e.g. if you need to preserve the quotes for some reason.

Comment: Why does your output list `""1,235.100000""` as **two columns**?

Comment: I get the correct output, your posted output is just not correct. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah ... should have noticed that.  Originally, I copy/pasted OP's `data` line *as is* (with the double quotes) which actually creates a string with *no quotes* :).  I caught that and fixed the quotes in my code, but I forgot to fix the output.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this would be to repair your input file; two quote characters together at the start of a column are seen as a quoted empty value and removed from your input when normal quoting rules are in effect. The double quotes at the end are seen as part of the value.

You can repair the values after the fact by post-processing each row:

```
def rejoin_quoted(row):
    new_row = []
    it = iter(row)
    for col in it:
         new_row.append(col)
         if col.startswith('""'):
             new_col = [col]
             for col in it:
                 new_col.append(col)
                 if col.endswith('""'):
                     new_row[-1] = ','.join(new_col).strip('"')
                     break
    return new_row
```

Demo:

```
>>> row = ['02 JAN 2014', 'FEB 2014', 'A', '1.00', '', '', '""1', '235.100000""', '""1', '230.00""', 'Column']
>>> rejoin_quoted(row)
['02 JAN 2014', 'FEB 2014', 'A', '1.00', '', '', '1,235.100000', '1,230.00', 'Column']
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to slightly modify your data in order to explicitly specify a quote-char and the escape character:

```
data = '02 JAN 2014,FEB 2014,A,1.00,,,"\"1,235.100000\"","\"1,230.00\"",Column'
parsed = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', escapechar='\\')
```